# How many pageview requests it would send to GA metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, hashchange

Whether this code is fine to implement for UA to track hashchange Urls:

```
 ga ('send', 'pageview', {
   'page': location.pathname+location.search+location.hash, 
   'title': location.pathname+location.search+location.hash});
```

How many pageview requests it would record in GA everytime the event fire?

Answer (score 1):

Every time that line of code executes, one Google Analytics Pageview will fire. See [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) for more details on Pageview tracking.

Also, [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) might be helpful. It prints info on any Google Analytics hits sent to the JS console.

Comment: Okay.How to search how may hits sent to GA through JS console?